# add httpModule Applicationhost.config only for local development

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I have a unique problem that I think someone out here may be able to help with! I create an HttpModule that needs to run on all requests but only in when the app is running in localhost during the development. I have successfully created the httpModule and was able to manually install it in web.config. However this involves having to remove it manually when we deploy to real server. So what I am trying to do is create a nuget package that my devs can install in the project that will install the httpModule to the ApplicationHost.config file in localhost IISExpress in the hidden .vs folder for the project. So I guess my question is two parts

1) How do I get a nuget package to add the HttpModule to applicaitonhost.config and not web.config ! 
2) Will doing that prevent the module from being deployed with my project?

The HTTPmodule just adds some headers and cookies to every request that are not needed when the project is not running on local host! Is what am trying to do even possible?

Comment: You can keep it in the web.config, and use config transforms to control whether it ends up in the final configuration or not. No need to modify applicationHost.config.

Comment: Oh my Lord, I can't believe I missed that ! That is perfect thank you for pointing it out